# Automatic say yes to make ext3 file system on disk with mkfs.ext3

Tags: bash, ext3

I am working on a script where I make a ext3 filesystem on a disk, the problem is that the script ask user to either say yes or no:

```
 root@ubuntu:/home/school#  mkfs.ext3 /dev/sdc
 mke2fs 1.42 (29-Nov-2011)
 /dev/sdc is entire device, not just one partition!
 Proceed anyway? (y,n)
```

I have tried to put -y before mkfs and after sdc but that didnt work. Do anyone have any solutions to do this without user interaction?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**You should probably not make a filesystem on an entire disk.** Instead, you should make it on a *partition* on the disk (which would be something like `/dev/sdc1` rather than `/dev/sdc`). If you don't already have a partition you can make that first. The partition can (essentially) be the size of the whole disk, if you like. Even when you only want *one* partition on the disk, you still need to actually make the partition. Many utilities and applications (and people!) will not work, or will behave strangely, if your filesystems are not on *partitions*.

If you **really know what you are doing** and you're sure you want to make a filesystem that is not part of any partition, you can do make `mkfs.ext3` do this without prompting the user, by using the `-F` flag. This is almost always preferable to [simulating interactive input with a pipe](https://askubuntu.com/a/428476/22949) (it's simpler, more self-documenting, and what if something unexpected happens and the question is something else, like the device already being mounted?). On the other hand, in some situations (with some utilities) you may find you have to pipe `y` or `yes` to a utility, so it's a good technique to be aware of.

From the description of the `-F` flag in [`man mkfs.ext3`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/mkfs.ext3.8.html):

> Force **mke2fs** to create  a  filesystem,  even  if  the  specified
>   device is not a partition on a block special device, or if other
>   parameters do not make sense.   In  order  to  force  **mke2fs** to
>   create  a filesystem even if the filesystem appears to be in use or is
>   mounted (a truly dangerous thing to do), this option  must be
>   specified twice.

So, you can use `mkfs.ext3 -F /dev/sdc`.

But, to reiterate, **you should probably not do this at all because filesystems should almost always be created on a *partition*.**

Comment: Thanks for help! You are surely right. I made a partition now which i made a filesystem on.

Comment: By and large, Linux software will handle it fine, but Windows will see it as blank and offer to format it.  It also can cause problems installing a boot loader to the disk, and locks you out of resizing and adding another partition later.

Comment: @psusi Some time ago, I've had problems in Ubuntu, recognizing and automatically mounting filesystems not containing in partitions, on the desktop. I'm not sure if the problem was with `udisks`, Nautilus, a combination of the two, or something else. I believe there may also be problems booting to a filesystem that is not on a partition.

Answer (score 5):

There is no `-y` option for `mkfs.ext3`, you can check by readin its manual page (`man mkfs.ext3`). However, there is a program called `yes` that is specifically designed to do what you want:

```
NAME
   yes - output a string repeatedly until killed
```

So, you could run:

```
 yes | mkfs.ext3  /dev/sdc
```

**However**, bear in mind that you are attempting to create a filesystem on the entire device instead of on a single partition and this is probably *not* what you want to do. You should first create a partition on the disk and *then* create a filesystem on that partition.

Comment: Is there the opposite for `no`?

Comment: @Petah you can use `yes no`. The `yes` program will repeat anything you give it (see `man yes`).